# How use an array of letters as a filter for foreach loop in Php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to loop through an array while using another array as a sort of  "filter":

```
$aa = ["b","r","i", "g", "i", "t", "t", "e"];
$bb = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "r"];

foreach($aa as $b){
  if($b == $bb){
    echo "Give me an ". $b;
    echo "\n";
  }else{
    echo "Give me a ". $b;
    echo "\n";

  }
}
```

So I want it to compare the letters in $aa Against the list of letters in $bb to determine whether it should echo "an or "a" to be gramatically correct.
The only way I've been able to get it to work correctyly is to do this:

```
foreach($aa as $b){
  if($b == "a" or $b == "e" or $b == "i" or $b == "o" or $b == "u" or $b == "r"){
    echo "Give me an ". $b;
    echo "\n";
  }else{
    echo "Give me a ". $b;
    echo "\n";

  }
}
```

Comment: Look into [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `in_array` here is the [official documentation in php.net](https://www.php.net/in_array),

I would do it in this way:

```
foreach($aa as $b){
   if(in_array($b, $bb)){
      echo "Give me an ". $b;
      echo "\n";
   }else{
      echo "Give me a ". $b;
      echo "\n";

   }
 }
```

Comment: Or further reduce: `foreach($aa as $a) printf("Give me a%s %s\n", in_array($a, $bb) ? 'n' : '', $a);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```php
<?php

$aa = ["b","r","i", "g", "i", "t", "t", "e"];
$bb = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "r"];

foreach($aa as $b){
    if(in_array($b, $bb)){
        echo "Give me an ". $b . "<br/>";
        echo "\n";
    }else{
        echo "Give me a ". $b . "<br/>";
        echo "\n";

    }
}

exit(0);
```

Output:

```
Give me a b
Give me an r
Give me an i
Give me a g
Give me an i
Give me a t
Give me a t
Give me an e
```